# How to use FileLists as rake dependencies

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm using rake to help compile Coffeescript for a Chrome extension I'm writing.

My Rakefile looks like this:

```
COFFEE = FileList['src/*.coffee']
JS = COFFEE.ext 'js'

directory 'extension'

rule '.js' => ['.coffee', 'extension'] do |t|
  `coffee -c -o extension #{t.source}`
end

desc "Build the extension in the 'extension' directory"
task :build => ['extension', JS] do
  cp File.join('src', 'manifest.json'), 'extension'
end
```

When I only have one `.coffee` file in my `src` directory, there's no problem. But as soon as I have more than one `.coffee` files it errors:

```
$ rake build
> rake aborted!
> Don't know how to build task 'src/app.js src/background.js'
>
> Tasks: TOP => build
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Is it possible to specify a `FileList` as a dependency? How else would I tell rake that I want all my Coffeescript files compiled durring the build task?

Comment: Not at my machine ATM, so I can’t test my hunch, but I’m wondering  if the issue might be you are nesting arrays in your dependency. Have you tried splatting the FileList?

Comment: @kopischke Yes, that works, and I'm going to go ahead and use it. Though it's kind of annoying that rake doesn't automatically handle that case.

Comment: Yeah, kinda, though you can argue it is a consistent contract. Mind if I turn this into an answer you could accept?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rake’s dependency list is an Array of task names. When you use a FileList as one of its elements, you nest arrays – effectively, this:

```
task :build => ['extension', ['src/app.js', 'src/background.js']] do
```

Rake just uses the String representation of all passed dependency Array elements, which is why it complains about being unable to build a `'src/app.js src/background.js'` task (note how this is one string).

Splatting your FileList (or flattening the dependency Array) will solve the issue, i.e.:

```
task :build => ['extension', *JS] do
```

or

```
task :build => ['extension', JS].flatten do
```

Comment: Which is why, of course, [the `concat` approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14534924/990363) also works.

Comment: A bit more nicer/rakier syntax could be task :build => JS.add('extension') ?

Comment: @inger More Rake specific maybe, but nicer I'm not sure about: you still need to understand the underlying data structure, and I’d argue that solving that with core Ruby functionality (the splat operator in particular is a common Ruby idiom) is nice in itself :).

Comment: When using a "DSL", I prefer to stay withing the little language, without resorting to the (powerful) host language.. It's "simpler" and it allows non-Ruby-speakers to just look at the API doc of FileList. No need to understand everything underneath.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
files = Dir.entries('path/to/scripts').select { |f| f.include? '.coffee' }
files.each do |file_path|
  `coffee -c -o extension #{file_path}`
end
```

Comment: The error is not raised by the CoffeScript processing rule, but by the task that adds its input files as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

So far in my search it looks like the only way to accomplish what I want is to either have a task which loops through my `FileList` and compiles each one explicitly (like in the answer from  @nicooga). Or, I can loop through everything in the `FileList` and add it as a dependency to the build task.

I don't like either of these because `rake` has `FileList`s for getting groups of files, `rule`s for defining how to handle kinds of files, and a nice syntax for defining dependencies, but apparently no way to combine all three of those together.

So, my solution for now is to go with the second option, adding each file as a dependency. The shortest way I've found to do this is to `concat` the `FileList` onto the dependency array. So now my build task looks like this:

```
task :build => ['extension'].concat(JS) do
  cp File.join('src', 'manifest.json'), 'extension'
end
```

And thanks to the comment by @kopischke, this can even be shortened to `['extension' *JS]` using the splat operator.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but a FileList is lazy, and that is useful, especially if you have lots of file matching.
Think of C or C++ where you potentially can have many that require dependencies.

Most of the answers here require the FileList to be expanded/evaluated. Since Rake is Ruby and task is where the last argument is basically a Hash, you will be evaluating the array.

One of the answers suggests ['extension', JS].flatten. This approach will search the directory and collect all the .js files. This approach is fine when you have a task that will always get executed/invoked. However, you don't want to evaluate the FileList and invoke its search if the task is will not get executed/invoked.

The best way to use a FileList is the following

```
fl = FileList['extension', "src/*.coffee"] do |c|
   c.ext('js')
end
file "somefile" => fl do
   #some stuff
end
```

Then if "somefile" doesn't exist, or the "somefile" task is not even invoked, the read of your Rakefile doesn't invoke the FileList expansion, saving a bunch of time.